# Magento - Form with 2 Submit Buttons (one without Validation)

Tags: magento

I have a Magento Form with validation using:

```
var dataForm = new VarienForm('...');
```

I would like to have 2 submit buttons, one with validation (this is OK) and one without the validation.

How can I configure the 2nd submit button so that it does not trigger the Form's Validation?

Answer (score 0):

Would adding a normal submit button work?

```
<input type="submit" value="submit">
```

The only reason you use the `var dataForm = new VarienForm('...');` is to enable the validation side of things. You would just have to ensure that the `action` value of the form tag was pointing to the correct URL

Comment: I would like to have a form with 2 Submit buttons. One button doing client side (browser) validation (ie using VarienForm) and the other without any client side validation. If I set both buttons as <input type="submit" value="submit"> and use the VarienForm then both buttons trigger the client side validation.

Comment: Yes, but you would only use the VarienForm on one of the buttons, in the onclick event...the other wouldn't have this

Comment: How? In all of Magento's examples I found, VarienForm is created globally (not in the onclick event). I have tried to create it in the onclick event but then I could not get the form validation to work. Could you provide an example onclick code that would create the VarienForm and do the validation? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Magento contact form also does some Zend-level validation after you've submitted the form. You can see this inside:

```
 app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php
```

Check the PostAction() method...

Comment: I would like to have a form with 2 Submit buttons. One button doing client side (browser) validation (ie using VarienForm) and the other without any client side validation.